# Intercepting AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently facing problem intercepting AJAX Calls.
I know how I can somehow intercept AJAX Calls at some level by ajaxSetup().
But I have one question: ajaxSetup() intercepts all calls within the document. I DON'T WANT TO DO THAT.
What I'm really trying to do is changing the default type 'GET' to 'POST' of some calls. And for that I need to use ajaxSetup(). Is there any way how can I 'setup' only selected or 'ajax calls which follow a certain URL pattern'?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `beforeSend` in `$.ajaxSetup()`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
        settings.type = settings.url.indexOf("foo") > -1 ? "POST" : "GET"
    }
});
```

GET request changed to POST -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yj1j6huw/)
(check the network panel for the changed submission method)